# How to Lock chrome profile or chrome browser with a password

Tags: google-chrome

I tried enabling the New Management flag and adding a supervised user. But the option to lock a user profile was not activated. Is there a way to password protect a chrome user profile or lock the whole browser(like firefox's master password)

Comment: The new profile management under `chrome://flags` should be the way to go. Did you restart after setting the flag to enabled?

Comment: @Atzmon Yes. did a restart after setting the flag to enabled. then added a supervised user as well. but we can only limit supervised user's access to the internet from that. Still cannot lock my main profile with a password.

Comment: @Atzmon Are you able to do it in your browser?

Comment: Sorry, now I see the passwords can only be set in Chromebooks. If you need the password protection and not the supervised features (parental controls) then you can sign in to Chrome with a gmail account. Alternatively, if you need to protect settings so that only you can change them, go with the supervised user and then "Exit and childlock".

Comment: @Atzmon Thank you for you response and sorry for my late reply. I will try what you suggest.

Comment: I can not find a solution until now. I need only to put password before chrome open

Answer (score 0):

Install veracrypt, create a 2Gb password protected virtual drive s: ([link](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Beginner%27s%20Tutorial))
then start chrome like this:

```
set CHROME_EXE=C:/PROGRA~2/Google/Chrome/APPLIC~1/chrome.exe
set CHROME_DATA=s:\secure-profile
mkdir %CHROME_DATA%
%CHROME_EXE% --user-data-dir=%CHROME_DATA%
```

This chrome will only start when S: is mounted using veracrypt (windows and linux compatible). All the chrome data will be inaccessible without the password for S: